# C# JToken.SelectTokens Method - what JPath expression?

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have json text like this:

```
{
"course_editions": {
"2014/SL": [
  {
    "grades": {
      "course_units_grades": {
        "159715": {
          "1": {
            "value_symbol": "4",
            "exam_session_number": 1,
            "exam_id": 198172,
            "value_description": {
              "en": "good",
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "course_grades": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "grades": {
      "course_units_grades": {
        "159796": {
          "1": {
            "value_symbol": "5",
            "exam_session_number": 1,
            "exam_id": 198259,
            "value_description": {
              "en": "very good",
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "course_grades": {}
    }
  },
```

I would like to use JToken.SelectTokens Method from Namespace: Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

I've tried like this:

```
string json_response = GetResponse(sign(url_courses));
var courses_tokens = JObject.Parse(json_response).SelectTokens("['course_editions'].['2014/SL'].[*].['grades'].*")
```

It doesn't work. I would like to get only these numbers after `course_unit_grades` and before `"1"`. So in this example only: `"159715"` and `"159796"` to be able to use all of them, one by one in

```
foreach(var lp in courses_tokens) {
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This is one possible way :**

```
var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
var coursesTokens = jobj.SelectTokens("course_editions.2014/SL[*].grades.course_units_grades")
                        .Select(o => o.First) //get the first child of `course_units_grades`
                        .Cast<JProperty>() //cast to JProperty
                        .Select(o => o.Name); //get the name of the property
foreach (string coursesToken in coursesTokens)
{
    Console.WriteLine(coursesToken);
}
```

<kbd>[`Dotnetfiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/shRQje)</kbd>

**given json sample at the bottom, the output is as follow :**

```
159715
159796
```

**json sample :**

```
var json = @"{
   'course_editions': {
      '2014/SL': [
         {
            'grades': {
               'course_units_grades': {
                  '159715': {
                     '1': {
                        'value_symbol': '4',
                        'exam_session_number': 1,
                        'exam_id': 198172,
                        'value_description': {
                           'en': 'good'
                        }
                     }
                  }
               },
               'course_grades': {}
            }
         },
         {
            'grades': {
               'course_units_grades': {
                  '159796': {
                     '1': {
                        'value_symbol': '5',
                        'exam_session_number': 1,
                        'exam_id': 198259,
                        'value_description': {
                           'en': 'very good'
                        }
                     }
                  }
               },
               'course_grades': {}
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}";
```

Comment: My example doesn't provide this situation but there can be more than one child in `course_units_grades`, max. 3, but in this particular case I have a problem with `.Select(o => o.First)`, Is there any other way ?